# Alternative measurement for Cross Entropy Loss than accuracy when using soft labeling?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, accuracy, measurement, cross-entropy

Suppose one has multi-class ($n>2$) data, where class labels are soft, e.g. two samples of for 3-classed data might look like:

```
cls   1     2     3
1. {0.90, 0.05, 0.05}
2. {0.30, 0.40, 0.30}
```

where the *main* class for each is still specified by the max probability, i.e. sample 1 is class 1 and sample 2 is class 2.

Further, suppose the predicted probabilities for classes for these two samples are:

```
cls   1     2     3
1. {0.88, 0.07, 0.05}
2. {0.37, 0.36, 0.27}
```

Then accuracy as a measurement is a bit too stringent.

By this I mean, the predicted class probability would result in sample 1 being labeled as class 1 (correct) and sample 2 labeled as class 1 (incorrect); however, the probabilities for sample 1 were only slightly off (and for class 3 were perfect) and as for sample 2, the predicted probability of the main class was only $0.04$ off.

Is there / what is a better measurement to reflect the quality of the predicted probabilities than accuracy?

Comment: Proper [tag:scoring-rules] such as log-loss and Brier score are some alternatives which make use of the fine-grained probability information.